# How to detect if not all elements in vector are quoted

Tags: r, rlang

Say I have this vector:

```
vars <- c(1, "2")
```

Since those two elements are in the same vector, they are both coerced to character. Even if I treat them as independent elements on a list, once they are extracted from the same vector, they keep their type on the list:

```
sapply(as.list(vars), class)
[1] "character" "character"
```

What function would find that not all of the elements in vector `vars` are of type character? Maybe another way to put it is: what function would detect that not all of the elements on vector `vars` are quoted?

Comment: Why do you need to know/do this?

Comment: I'm writing a function that takes a second argument; sometimes that argument is a quoted numeric, in which case it refers to a rowname. Sometimes it's just numeric, in which case it indicates a parameter to make a calculation.

Comment: I suggest changing your approach such that your vector only takes all elements of the same type.  Or, you can go with the answer below and use a list to contain different types.

Comment: Once you run `vars <- c(1, "2")`, the `c()` function will coerce all values to the same type. Any type information is lost by the time the value is set for `vars`. You can look at the parse tree of ` c(1, "2")` before evaluation to see the types, but once `c()` is actually evaluated, there's no going back.

Comment: `sometimes that argument is a quoted numeric, in which case it refers to a rowname. Sometimes it's just numeric` but at any given time it would be only one? So `vars` is either `vars <- 1` or `vars <- "2"` but not `vars <- c(1, "2")` ?

Comment: @RonakShah originally, sometimes `vars <- c(1, 2)` and other times was `c(1, "2")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of keeping in a `vector`, create a `list` which can have multiple `type` for each element

```
vars <- list(1, "2")
sapply(vars, class)
#[1] "numeric"   "character"
```

---

When we start this as a `vector`, there is no way to know which element should be numeric or character because both the elements once created are `character`

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't hard to change my code and take those arguments as a list. However, I still wonder if there is an `rlang` or quasiquotation method to detect this.

Comment: @DavidJorquera  My point was based on after you created the object.  If you are passing this in a function.  You may have more tools available to capture ie. substitute, deparse, match.call etc.  or some options from rlang.  It is not clear how your function takes this as input.  So, it is difficult to say which way it should be